# How do I disallow robots to access links on a certain port?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a private web server set up on a non-conventional port (say 6677). All people can have access to the whole site's urls from 6677. The links by `mysite:6677` are also indexed by Google, which is not desireable, as I need to keep port 6677 discreet as a kind of workaround behind the front proxy which runs on 80.

So, how can I disallow access to 6677 in `robots.txt`?

Comment: Why it is indexed? Does the `mysite:6677` restricted by login page? (I guess yes since it's the site's admin). Then, why don't you just add propre meta tag to disallow indexing?

Comment: No it is not restricted. people can see all the publically accessible urls from either of the ports. How can I add meta tags?

Comment: Here is an [example](http://www.lionessconsulting.com/Tip071502.htm).

Comment: @j0k assuming that the example meta work, it is undesirable since it still exposes the port 6677 in html code.

Comment: Why does it expose the port? The HTML file has no knowledge of the port through which it is being accessed and there should be no need to mention it. Note that if you use the META tags then you need to **allow** robots.txt - as mentioned in my linked answer.

Comment: @w3d. There are not few pages that I can manipulate their html meta tags. I am talking about making the WHOLE site invisible from port 6677. Add the meta to my template, make the site invisible on port 80 too, which is very bad!

Comment: Ah, you did not specify in your question that _the same_ site can be accessed on both ports! (A robots.txt is also a problem is such cases.) In that case you probably need to implement some server-side scripting in order to detect the port being used and conditionally return an `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` header. In PHP you could check `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`.

Comment: @w3d, I edited the question to avoid the ambiguity. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to disallow crawler access to `example.com:6677` using robots.txt then you simply have to host your robots.txt file on the appropriate port, ie:

```
http://example.com:6677/robots.txt
```

The specification does not allow you to specify a port in the robots.txt file itself. Any paths specified use the same protocol, port number and host by which the file is accessed.

But, as mentioned in [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/34171/1243), disallowing in robots.txt does not necessarily prevent the URL from being *indexed*; it prevents it from being *crawled*.

---

However, as noted in the comments, it seems that the *same site* is accessible from both port 80 and port 6677. But only port 6677 should be blocked from crawlers.

Since both ports access the same site then they would both share a common robots.txt file and so both sites would be blocked, unless you conditionally returned a different robots.txt file depending on which port was used to access the site. This could perhaps be done using .htaccess and an internal rewrite, but I don't think a robots.txt is what you require since you could still run the risk of these URLs being indexed.

In my opinion you need to conditionally check for the port in your server-side script and send the appropriate META tag or HTTP response header back to the client. In PHP you could do this with something like the following (near the top of your script):

```
<?php
// Block robots from port 6677
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '6677') {
  header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex');
}
?>
```

Comment: robots.txt is already accessible through http://example.com:6677/, just like any other publically accessible file of the site.

Comment: Then your robots.txt file _should_ already be preventing crawler access to these files, unless there is an error in the file? Is the link in SERPs a URL-only link, or is it complete with title and description?

Comment: I'm not sure what SERP is. Just to clarify my aim: I don't wan ANY of the urls:6677/ become exposed in google search results.

Comment: SERP - Search Engine Results Page. If you don't want the URLs to appear at all in the SERPs then don't disallow in robots.txt. You need to either add a noindex robots META tag to the page (as j0k suggests in comments) or return an `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP response header. If, however, you need to prevent any unauthorised access then you'll need to implement some kind of password authentication.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it only through robots.txt?

Comment: You can't specify the port _inside_ the robots.txt file. You would need to conditionally return a different robots.txt file depending on which port was used to access the site (via server-side scripting). But, as mentioned in my answer, I don't think a robots.txt is what you require, since disallowing robots with robots.txt does not necessarily prevent the linked URLs from appearing in Googles search results (SERPs)! I have updated my answer.